# Is it possible to install nvidia drivers from a live USB onto an existing Kubuntu instance on my computer?

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, kubuntu

the latest nvidia drivers installed from Discover completely broke them (I believe they were version 525 or 530, I didn't anticipate everything to break after installing them. They were on version 525 prior to this) Restarting after being prompted had me stuck on “`finished plymouth-quit.service - terminate plymouth boot screen`”

Tried restarting, and now I can't boot into my desktop, I'm stuck with command line only as all that shows up is “`hid-generic (a bunch of numbers) No inputs registered, leaving`” it usually would eventually get to the login screen from there but now it just hangs there.

I can do ctrl-alt-f2 to get to command line, but sudo apt install nvidia-driver-530 just results in “`unable to fetch archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with —fix-missing?`” This is extra unfortunate as I ran `sudo apt autoremove --purge nvidia* && sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525` with the latter command not working due to the previously mentioned error.

Since I'm stuck here, I wanted to know how to install nvidia drivers onto my computer's Kubuntu install from a live USB, if possible. I genuinely have no idea why this unable to fetch archives stuff is happening, maybe the internet isn't working in this state? If it's not possible to reinstall drivers from a live USB, is there any other way to repair this? Or is this linux attempt essentially cooked & I'll need to reinstall?

card is GTX 1060 6GB, OS is Kubuntu 23.04.

Please let me know if there is any more helpful information I can provide.

Comment: What you want to do does not fix the errors apt gives you so no  it wont work.  `sudo apt install —fix-missing`  why does that not work? And the alternative would be to re-install --without formatting- (only mounting); it will leave all  settings as is.

Comment: My access to the internet seems to be broken, as when I try doing that it givens me  errors like "failed to fetch" and "temporary failure resolving" with different repositories (if thats what they are). Seems like ill need to reinstall without formatting, is that possible if I have the install on two drives?

Comment: Alright i reinstalled. Had to reinstall the flatpaks I had, but the desktop works again. Are there any tips for the future to avoid having my install just completely break from installing Nvidia drivers in Discover? I heard disabling Secure Boot/CSM might have been needed to do it safely but that would lock me out of my Windows 11 partition.

Comment: Then you did something bad. w/o internet a re-install is indeed warranted (=or= you need to really know yourself how to fix that problem. It is very difficult to help there :)). "break from installing Nvidia drivers in Discover" but I doubt that was the problem. THAT is pretty easy to do: we have the `ubuntu-drivers` command nowadays; I assume kde has this too? It is a good tool for this